# Radon in water mitigation

Tags: water, radon, water-filtration

I need to install a Radon in water mitigation system. Is there a Do It Yourself way to do this with a simple aeration or filter system. I already have a pH adjustment system in my basement ( Calcium Carbonate). Can I piggy back a filter or Aerator on it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have well water or do you get your water from a public water supply? If it's the latter, then I would certainly contact the water company. If it is the former, there are two main methods of treating for radon in water: granular activated carbon (GAC) and aeration.

I recommend this link for more information...

https://archive.epa.gov/water/archive/web/html/basicinformation-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Aeration will release most radon gas from the water, but you want to vent it outside. However, radon comes from the decomposition of radium. Radium is chemically similar to calcium ( and Ba, Sr, and Mg) so a conventional water softener will remove radium before it produces radon . ( I don't understand your pH adjustment system for a home). That is what my local water company was required to do ( soften to remove radium = remove radon, indirectly).

Comment: Thanks. My pH adjuster system is simply a tank full of Calcium Carbonate granules. Incominh pH 5.4 outgoing 7. I have well water.

Comment: That is peculiar- acid water with radon. ; Acidic water is typical of very low Alkalai earths - mostly calcium. Radon comes from limestone because of the radium it typically contains ; radium breaks down to radon gas which then moves with the water. The Niagara limestone of great lakes/northern Il is a classic source of radon. That is, if you don't have calcium , you are unlikely to have radon.